# python command string.replace(old, lower(), 'something') returns old string

Tags: python, python-2.7, str-replace

```
s1 = 'GSHMGLYELSASNFELHVAQGDHFIKFFAPWCGHCKALAPTWEQLALGLEHSETVKIGKVDbTQHYELbSGNQVRGYPTLLWFRDGKKVDQYKGKRDLESLREYVESQLQR'
```

This is a string I would like to replace the lowercase letters to a certain uppercase letter, say, 'C'. the command I am using is :

```
string.replace(s1, s1.lower(), 'C'),
```

problem:the resulting string is still the same as the old one, b is 'b' and not 'C'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is too complex for simple "replace" method. Use regexp instead:

```
import re    
s1 = "GaHMxLYELmASNFElHVAQG"
s2 = re.sub(r"[a-z]", "C", s1)
print s2
```

It will print "GCHMCLYELCASNFECHVAQG"

[a-z] means "any letter from a to z" - add extra lower letters for it for your language, if needed. For example, for russian this pattern will be: [a-zа-я]

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you're trying to replace a lowercase copy of the entire string with `'C'`. You're also seemingly not assigning the result of `string.replace` with anything, which won't work. `replace` doesn't modify in place, it returns a new copy of the string with the replacements applied.

You'll need to iterate over the string and replace any lowercase letters.

```
s1 = 'GSHMGLYELSASNFELHVAQGDHFIKFFAPWCGHCKALAPTWEQLALGLEHSETVKIGKVDbTQHYELbSGNQVRGYPTLLWFRDGKKVDQYKGKRDLESLREYVESQLQR'
replaced_string = ''.join(x if x.isupper() else 'C' for x in s1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string.replace(s1, s1.lower(), 'C')
```

Will replace with 'C' only the *whole* string

```
gshmglyelsasnfelhvaqgdhfikffapwcghckalaptweqlalglehsetvkigkvdbtqhyelbsgnqvrgyptllwfrdgkkvdqykgkrdleslreyvesqlqr
```

If you want to substitute all the characters with a given property in a string what I suggest is to use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), in your case it will be:

```
s2 = re.sub("[a-z]", "C", s1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`s1.lower()` is equal to

```
>>> s1.lower()
'gshmglyelsasnfelhvaqgdhfikffapwcghckalaptweqlalglehsetvkigkvdbtqhyelbsgnqvrgyptllwfrdgkkvdqykgkrdleslreyvesqlqr'
```

So `string.replace(s1, s1.lower(), 'C')` searches string c1 for any occurances of that whole string of lower case characters, and if it finds any then it replaces each one with `'C'`.

Note that `string.replace` is also a method on strings themselves ever since Python 2.0 or so, `s1.replace(s1.lower(), 'C')` would do the exact same thing.

You can use a translation table:

```
>>> from string import maketrans, lowercase
>>> trans_table = maketrans(lowercase, 'C' * len(lowercase))
>>> s1.translate(trans_table)
```

Maketrans takes two strings of characters with equal lengths, and translate() then translates each occurence of a character in the first to its equivalent in the second.

`lowercase` is `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'`, and 'C' * len(lowercase) is simply a string of 26 Cs.